# Is there a Terminal command that I can use to shut down a mongod process in OS X?

Tags: macos, mongodb, shell, command-line

`mongod --shutdown` is not available on OS X. The only good way seems to be using the `mongo` interface. Can I shut down a `mongod` process that was started in the background using the `--fork` flag using the command line? Any way to use `kill` with `ps`?

I'm trying to shut down MongoDB using an npm `posttest` script (just a command that's run after my unit tests).

Comment: Why would `kill <pid>` not work?

Comment: I'm not exactly a command line whiz. How can I find the `pid`? `ps` does not seem to list all the processes. I have tried `ps -x | grep mongod` and could not find anything.

Comment: I'm not sure on Mac but on linux you use either `ps` which gives a list of active processes and their pid. Or you can start the process in the command line and request the latest started process id using `echo $!`.

Comment: Alternatively try: `mongo admin --eval "db.shutdownServer()"`.

Comment: I didn't know about that `--eval` command. That's fantastic. It tells me `DBClientCursor::init call() failed, server should be down...` and then shuts down. It works fine, but I'm just wondering if there is a way to suppress it or perhaps do it correctly. What does it mean?

Comment: You mean the output? If so try `mongo admin --eval "db.shutdownServer()" > /dev/null 2&>1`

Comment: Yeah, I get this: http://i.imgur.com/g6DeRD2.png

Comment: I guess I could pipe it to /dev/null, but I'm just wondering why that happens.

Comment: Lacky programming I guess, the devs didn't care too much for the Mac version. Anyway, don't worry about it, if it works, it works! -- Let me just put this stuff in an answer so other people can be helped in the future.

Comment: I like the solution. You should post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either find out the pid using `ps | grep mongod` or `echo $!` after starting it up (the variable `$!` holds the pid of the last started process) and use `kill pid`.

Or, simply use `mongo admin --eval "db.shutdownServer()"`, which throws an error but seems to work anyway. You can always pipe undesired output to `/dev/null`.

Comment: Also, using pgrep mongod returns only the process id, which I found helpful.